# Problema de validación con Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

estoy pasando el codigo controlador a ajax. Una de las tareas que debo cumplir es que el programa verifique si un dato entado por el usuario exciste o no en la BD. Hasta ahora logro que muestre un mensaje cuando el dato esta en la BD o cuando la estructura del codigo no es el correcta. El error esta a la hora de verificar todo y se cumplan los requisitos, me oculte los mensajes de error. Hasta ahora, se queda el input con la clase is-invalid y el div con clase invalid-tooltip, sale pero sin texto. He movido pedazos de codigo a otras partes del programa a ver si se quita, pero nada. Abajo les dejo varios codigo.

**PD:** Las funciones `validarCodigo($('#text_codigo_postgrado').val())`, `BuscarCodigo($text_codigo_postgrado)`, `InsertarPostgrado()`, `LastID()` y `InsertarPostgradoInt()` trabajan sin problema. Si necesitan que suba un algo en especifico, me lo comunican. Gracias de antemano.

boton que dispara el evento:

```
$("#text_codigo_postgrado").focusout(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#codigo_exciste").hide();
        $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
        VerificarCodigo();
    
    });
```

Codigo de AJAX:

```
function VerificarCodigo() {

    if (!validarCodigo($('#text_codigo_postgrado').val())) {
        $("#codigo_exciste").show();
        $("#h1_codigo").html("Código Incorrecto");
        $('#text_codigo_postgrado').addClass("is-invalid");
        $('#text_codigo_postgrado').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        var datos = $("#form_postgrado").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../controlador/cc-postgrados.php?accion=1',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datos,
            success: function (e) {
                    $("#text_codigo_postgrado").addClass("is-invalid");
                    $("#codigo_exciste").show();
                    $("#h1_codigo").html(e);
                    
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Este switch es el encargado de ejecutar cada accion, segun el valor que le entre por la URL del Ajax. El otro tema seria lograr que despues de verificado el codigo, de la opcion de insertar un postgrado.

```
if (isset($_GET['accion'])){
        switch ($_GET['accion']) {
            case 1: //Verificar código
                $objcodigo = new Postgrado();
                $buscarCod = $objcodigo->BuscarCodigo($text_codigo_postgrado);
                if (count($buscarCod) > 0){
                    echo "Código en uso";
                }else{
                    echo `$("#codigo_exciste").hide()`;
                    echo `$('#text_codigo_postgrado').removeClass("is-invalid")`;
                }
                break;
                
            case 2: //Insertar Postgrado Nacional o Internacional
                $post = new Postgrado($rbtnImpartido_Centro, $num_cant_alum, $num_cant_horas, $text_fecha_Inicio, $text_fecha_Final, $text_codigo_postgrado, $rbtnTipo, $select_tema, $select_profesor);
                $Nac = $post->InsertarPostgrado();
    
                $ID = $post->LastID();
                $ultimoID = $ID[0]['ultimoId'];
    
                //Insetar Postgrado Internacional
                if ($rbtnTipo == 2) {
                    $postI = new PostgradoInt($ultimoID, $num_cant_alum_ext, $select_paises);
                    $Int = $postI->InsertarPostgradoInt();
                }
                break;
                    
            default:
                echo "Acción no detectada";
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes retornar código *Javascript* desde *PHP*, porque no se va a ejecutar, lo más adecuado es devolver una respuesta con error (verdadero/falso) y mensaje, de preferencia, en formato JSON para que sea manejable de la manera más fácil:

```
    // Crear arreglo con valores por defecto
    $salida = ['error' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Acción no reconocida'];
    // Definir acción con asignación ternaria
    $accion = (isset($_GET['accion'])) ? $_GET['accion'] : 0;
    // Validar acción
    switch ($accion) {
        case 1: //Verificar código
            $objcodigo = new Postgrado();
            $buscarCod = $objcodigo->BuscarCodigo($text_codigo_postgrado);
            if (count($buscarCod) > 0){
                $salida['mensaje'] = "Código en uso";
            }else{
                $salida['error'] = false;
                $salida['mensaje'] = 'Código disponible';
            }
            break;
            
        case 2: //Insertar Postgrado Nacional o Internacional
            // *********** Antes de ejecutar esto debes verificar cómo creas las variables **************
            $post = new Postgrado($rbtnImpartido_Centro, $num_cant_alum, $num_cant_horas, $text_fecha_Inicio, $text_fecha_Final, $text_codigo_postgrado, $rbtnTipo, $select_tema, $select_profesor);
            $Nac = $post->InsertarPostgrado();

            $ID = $post->LastID();
            $ultimoID = $ID[0]['ultimoId'];

            //Insetar Postgrado Internacional
            if ($rbtnTipo == 2) {
                $postI = new PostgradoInt($ultimoID, $num_cant_alum_ext, $select_paises);
                $Int = $postI->InsertarPostgradoInt();
            }
            $salida['error'] = false;
            $salida['mensaje'] = 'Postgrado insertado correctamente';
            break;
                
        default:
            // El mensaje por defecto ya está definido
            break;
    }
    // Devolver resultado en formato JSON
    echo json_encode($salida);
```

Siempre se devolverá el arreglo, independientemente de si la acción fue definida o no. En *Javascript* simplemente analizas el valor de error para determinar las acciones a realizar:

```
function VerificarCodigo() {
    if (!validarCodigo($('#text_codigo_postgrado').val())) {
        $("#codigo_exciste").show();
        $("#h1_codigo").html("Código Incorrecto");
        $('#text_codigo_postgrado').addClass("is-invalid");
        $('#text_codigo_postgrado').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        var datos = $("#form_postgrado").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../controlador/cc-postgrados.php?accion=1',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datos,
            // Por defecto, jQuery tratará de interpretar los datos
            // como texto, json, entre otros
            // Conviene especificar lo que esperas recibir
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.error) {
                    // Hubo error
                    $("#text_codigo_postgrado").addClass("is-invalid");
                    $("#codigo_exciste").show();
                } else {
                    // No hubo error
                    $("#text_codigo_postgrado").removeClass("is-invalid");
                    $("#codigo_exciste").hide();
                }
                // Si quieres mostrar mensaje
                $("#h1_codigo").html(data.mensaje);
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes mucha razón. Ya puse el código que publicaste en el proyecto y funciona de maravilla. Lo estoy analizando para saber dónde estaba mi error y no cometerlo en un futuro. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si tienes dudas, pregunta. Y si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Básicamente, el error estaba en que desde PHP no devolvías una respuesta que pudiera interpretarse y en Javascript no analizabas el resultado devuelto por PHP.

Comment: Leyendo tu comentario entendí cuál fue el problema. Eso me sirve para acciones futuras. Hice la acción de insertar que era el ```case 2:``` en el switch y trabaja de lo más bien. Explícame cómo marco la respuesta como aceptada?? Le doy a la palomita?