# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un head desde una pagina php sin que se entre en ella?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Muchachos, tengo un dilema en cuanto a una validación que de registro que trato de hacer usando php y js. Espero alguien pueda darme algo de luz de como lograr esta cuestión.

Estoy recibiendo unos datos via Post en js que provienen de mi formulario como ven a continuación
este es mi JS

```
$("#formCrearCurso").submit(function (c) {
        c.preventDefault();
        var nombreCurso = document.getElementById("nombreCurso").value;
        var tipoCurso = document.getElementById("tipoCurso").value;
        var categoriaCurso = document.getElementById("categoriaCurso").value;
        var descripcionCurso = document.getElementById("descripcionCurso").value;
        var sedeCurso = document.getElementById("sedeCurso").value;
        var rectoriaCurso = document.getElementById("rectoriaCurso").value;
        var fechaCurso = document.getElementById("fechaCurso").value;
        var cuposCurso = document.getElementById("cuposCurso").value;
        var lugarCurso = document.getElementById("lugarCurso").value;
        var horarioCurso = document.getElementById("horariosCurso").value;
        var conferencistaCurso = document.getElementById("conferencistaCurso").value;
        var administradorCurso = document.getElementById("administradorCurso").value;
        opcionC = 1;

        $.ajax({
            url: "../funciones/crudCursos.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                nombreCurso: nombreCurso,
                categoriaCurso: categoriaCurso,
                tipoCurso: tipoCurso,
                descripcionCurso: descripcionCurso,
                sedeCurso: sedeCurso,
                rectoriaCurso: rectoriaCurso,
                horarioCurso: horarioCurso,
                lugarCurso: lugarCurso,
                fechaCurso: fechaCurso,
                conferencistaCurso: conferencistaCurso,
                cuposCurso: cuposCurso,
                administradorCurso: administradorCurso,
                opcionC: opcionC,
                success: function (data) {
                    // Hay error?
                    if(data.error) {
                        // No redirijas, simplemente muestra el mensaje
                        // El usuario podrá modificar el formulario y reintentar
                        alert(data.mensaje);
                    } else {
                        // El formulario se procesó correctamente
                        // Mostrar el mensaje adecuado
                        alert(data.mensaje);
                        // Aquí deberías actualizar el DOM
                        // Ya sea la lista de cursos
                        // O limpiar los campos del formulario para permitir agregar otro curso
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

Luego de que se capturen estos datos los envio con ajax a un archivo php que es el que se encarga de de ejecutar las funciones

```
   <?php
require_once "../conexion/conectDataBase.php";
require_once "../funciones/queryCursos.php";

$curso = new queryCursos();

$idCurso = (isset($_POST['idCurso'])) ? $_POST['idCurso'] : '';
$nombreCurso = (isset($_POST['nombreCurso'])) ? $_POST['nombreCurso'] : '';
$categoriaCurso = (isset($_POST['categoriaCurso'])) ? $_POST['categoriaCurso'] : '';
$tipoCurso = (isset($_POST['tipoCurso'])) ? $_POST['tipoCurso'] : '';
$descripcionCurso = (isset($_POST['descripcionCurso'])) ? $_POST['descripcionCurso'] : '';
$sedeCurso = (isset($_POST['sedeCurso'])) ? $_POST['sedeCurso'] : '';
$rectoriaCurso = (isset($_POST['rectoriaCurso'])) ? $_POST['rectoriaCurso'] : '';
$horarioCurso = (isset($_POST['horarioCurso'])) ? $_POST['horarioCurso'] : '';
$lugarCurso = (isset($_POST['lugarCurso'])) ? $_POST['lugarCurso'] : '';
$fechaCurso = (isset($_POST['fechaCurso'])) ? $_POST['fechaCurso'] : '';
$conferencistaCurso = (isset($_POST['conferencistaCurso'])) ? $_POST['conferencistaCurso'] : '';
$cuposCurso = (isset($_POST['cuposCurso'])) ? $_POST['cuposCurso'] : '';
$administradorCurso = (isset($_POST['administradorCurso'])) ? $_POST['administradorCurso'] : '';
$opcionC = (isset($_POST['opcionC'])) ? $_POST['opcionC'] : '';
$salida = ['error' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Acción no reconocida'];
switch ($opcionC) {
    case 1:

        $consultaCursoHorario = $curso ->consultaCursoHorario("$horarioCurso");
        $data = $consultaCursoHorario ->fetch_assoc();
        $horario = mysqli_num_rows($consultaCursoHorario);
        if($horario != 0){
            $salida['mensaje'] = 'Ya hay un curso en ese horario.';
        }else{
            $consultaCursoLugar = $curso ->consultaCursoLugar("$sedeCurso");
            $data3 = $consultaCursoLugar ->fetch_assoc();
            $lugar = mysqli_num_rows($consultaCursoLugar);
            if ($lugar != 0){
                $salida['mensaje'] = 'Ya hay un curso en ese lugar.';
            }else{
                $insertarCurso = $curso->insertarCurso(null, "$nombreCurso", "$categoriaCurso","$tipoCurso", "$descripcionCurso", "$sedeCurso", "$rectoriaCurso", "$horarioCurso", "$lugarCurso", "$fechaCurso", "$conferencistaCurso", "$cuposCurso", "$administradorCurso");
                $data1 = $insertarCurso->fetch_assoc();
                // El curso se insertó correctamente
                $salida['error'] = false; // No mostrar como error
                $salida['mensaje'] = 'El curso se insertó correctamente';
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        $actualizarCurso = $curso->actualizarCurso("$idCurso", "$nombreCurso","$categoriaCurso" ,"$tipoCurso", "$descripcionCurso", "$sedeCurso", "$horarioCurso", "$lugarCurso", "$fechaCurso", "$conferencistaCurso", "$cuposCurso");
        $data = $actualizarCurso->fetch_assoc();
        // El curso se actualizó correctamente?
        $salida['error'] = false;
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'El curso fue actualizado';
        break;
    case 3:
        $eliminarCurso = $curso->eliminarCurso("$idCurso");
        $data = $eliminarCurso->fetch_assoc();
        // El curso se eliminó correctamente?
        $salida['error'] = false;
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'El curso fue eliminado';
        break;

}
echo json_encode($salida);
?>
```

dichas funciones poseen los queries de mysql para la ejecución de consultas o inserciones las querys son estas y se encuentran en el archivo de queryCursos y como ven anteriormente las requiero

como verán  envio estos datos a un archivo aparte php que lo denomine crudCursos y hay un switch para pues según lo que se quiera se elimine el dato se actualice o se inserte. Y es en este ultimo donde quiero validar si ya existe un registro bien sea con un horario o lugar ya registrado, la cuestión es que trato de enviar por get a mi lado de frontend que esta esperando un el dato get para mostar una alerta, la cosa es que no logro que se envie ese dato como ven  que envió el header para que el front  pueda leer los get

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto.

Comment: listo, lo hice ya

Comment: @Triby y como devuelvo una variable desde el otro archivo?

Comment: Probablemente [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389441/problema-de-validaci%c3%b3n-con-ajax/389538#389538) te pueda servir para saber cómo enviar la respuesta desde PHP y analizarla en la petición AJAX.

Comment: @Triby Vi la respuesta, pero quiero tratar de mostrar mensaje, lo que se define en la respuesta para poder usar esa variable, pero no me deja.

Comment: @Triby, tienes razón ya actualice mi pregunta. Ahí en el codigo del switch puse que solo por ahora trato de validar una condición nada más

Comment: @Triby cabe resaltar que ambos códigos están en archivos diferentes

Comment: al darle en network, sale un listado pero no sale el de crudCursos.php salen otros menos ese ni siquiera cuando le doy al boton de guardar

Comment: sale lo siguiente en preview :  {error: true, mensaje: "Ya hay un curso en ese horario."}
error: true
mensaje: "Ya hay un curso en ese horario."  y en response :  {"error":true,"mensaje":"Ya hay un curso en ese horario."}

Comment: Ahora, como primera línea de la función `success` agrega `console.log(data);` debe aparecer en la consola el JSON con error y mensaje.

Comment: eso fue lo que hice puse el console.log dentro del succes y eso es lo que me devuelve, lo que te escribí en el comentario anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea principal de usar AJAX es mejorar la experiencia del usuario, que no tenga que volver a teclear todos los datos, por eso, hay que evitar redirigir o recargar toda la página.

Desde PHP debes considerar todas las opciones y devolver los valores adecuados:

```
$salida = ['error' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Acción no reconocida'];
switch ($opcionC) {
    case 1:

        $consultaCursoHorario = $curso ->consultaCursoHorario("$horarioCurso");
        $data = $consultaCursoHorario ->fetch_assoc();
        $horario = mysqli_num_rows($consultaCursoHorario);
        if($horario != 0){
            $salida['mensaje'] = 'Ya hay un curso en ese horario.';
        }else{
            $consultaCursoLugar = $curso ->consultaCursoLugar("$sedeCurso");
            $data3 = $consultaCursoLugar ->fetch_assoc();
            $lugar = mysqli_num_rows($consultaCursoLugar);
            if ($lugar != 0){
                $salida['mensaje'] = 'Mensaje de error para este caso';    
            }else{
                $insertarCurso = $curso->insertarCurso(null, "$nombreCurso", "$categoriaCurso","$tipoCurso", "$descripcionCurso", "$sedeCurso", "$rectoriaCurso", "$horarioCurso", "$lugarCurso", "$fechaCurso", "$conferencistaCurso", "$cuposCurso", "$administradorCurso");
                $data1 = $insertarCurso->fetch_assoc();
                // El curso se insertó correctamente
                $salida['error'] = false; // No mostrar como error
                $salida['mensaje'] = 'El curso se insertó correctamente';    
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        $actualizarCurso = $curso->actualizarCurso("$idCurso", "$nombreCurso","$categoriaCurso" ,"$tipoCurso", "$descripcionCurso", "$sedeCurso", "$horarioCurso", "$lugarCurso", "$fechaCurso", "$conferencistaCurso", "$cuposCurso");
        $data = $actualizarCurso->fetch_assoc();
        // El curso se actualizó correctamente?
        $salida['error'] = false;
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'El curso fue actualizado';    
        break;
    case 3:
        $eliminarCurso = $curso->eliminarCurso("$idCurso");
        $data = $eliminarCurso->fetch_assoc();
        // El curso se eliminó correctamente?
        $salida['error'] = false;
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'El curso fue eliminado';    
        break;

}
echo json_encode($salida);
```

Después, en tu petición AJAX analizas la respuesta:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "../funciones/crudCursos.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            nombreCurso: nombreCurso,
            categoriaCurso: categoriaCurso,
            tipoCurso: tipoCurso,
            descripcionCurso: descripcionCurso,
            sedeCurso: sedeCurso,
            rectoriaCurso: rectoriaCurso,
            horarioCurso: horarioCurso,
            lugarCurso: lugarCurso,
            fechaCurso: fechaCurso,
            conferencistaCurso: conferencistaCurso,
            cuposCurso: cuposCurso,
            administradorCurso: administradorCurso,
            opcionC: opcionC
        }, // Aquí terminan los datos a enviar
        success: function (data) {
            // Hay error?
            if(data.error) {
                // No redirijas, simplemente muestra el mensaje
                // El usuario podrá modificar el formulario y reintentar
                alert(data.mensaje);
            } else {
                // El formulario se procesó correctamente
                // Mostrar el mensaje adecuado
                alert(data.mensaje);
                // Aquí deberías actualizar el DOM
                // Ya sea la lista de cursos
                // O limpiar los campos del formulario para permitir agregar otro curso
            }
        }
    })
```

En este ejemplo se muestran los mensajes con alertas, pero convendría hacerlo con modales o diálogos como el de [jQuery.Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), de preferencia, alguno que te permita elegir colores (o tema) para error o éxito.

Comment: Este es el error que me sale al ejecutar no entiendo el porque de este        
    incaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at success (datatableCursos.js:187)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Dt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.S.param (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (datatableCursos.js:167)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: No se está recibiendo una respuesta desde PHP., por eso `data` no está definida. Revisa si hay algún error de sintaxis (en PHP), si no lo encuentras, actualiza nuevamente la pregunta.

Comment: he revisado y no encuentro error de sintaxis en mi archivo php, como te digo que al estar separados es decir tengo el archivo php por un lado y el js en otro. Voy a actualizar pregunta, a lo mejor sea algo que estoy ignorando

Comment: @Kam1, lo malo de copiar y pegar es que a veces no te das cuenta de errores obvios. Copié y pegué tu código sin darme cuenta que pusiste `success` como parte de los datos a enviar y debe ser una propiedad de la petición AJAX, revisa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: si, me acabo de dar cuenta, Gracias bro